# Prove that $\int_{E}f =\lim \int_{E}f_{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory

I'm doing exercise in Real Analysis of Folland, and got stuck on this problem. I try to use Fatou lemma but can't come to the conclusion. Can anyone help me. I really appreciate.

> > Consider a measure space $(X, M, \mu)$.Suppose $\{f_{n}\} \in L^{+}, f_{n} \rightarrow f$ pointwise and $\int f = \lim \int f_{n} < \infty$. Then $\int_{E} f = \lim \int_{E} f_{n}$ for all $E \in M$. However, this need not be true if $\int f = \lim \int f_{n} = \infty$

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By Fatou's lemma, we have

$$\int_E f \, d\mu \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int_E f_n \, d\mu . \tag{1}$$

Similarly,

$$\int_{X \backslash E} f\, d\mu  \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int_{X \backslash E} f_n\, d\mu . \tag{2}$$

Since $\int_X f\, d\mu = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_X f_n \, d\mu $, we get

$$\begin{align*} \int_{E} f\, d\mu  &= \int_X f \, d\mu - \int_{X \backslash E} f\, d\mu  \\ &\stackrel{(2)}{\geq} \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_X f_n \, d\mu - \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int_{X \backslash E} f_n \, d\mu \\ &= \limsup_{n \to \infty} \left( \int_X f_n \, d\mu - \int_{X \backslash E} f_n \, d\mu \right) = \limsup_{n \to \infty} \int_E f_n\, d\mu .  \tag{3}\end{align*}$$

Combining $(1)$ and $(3)$ shows

$$\int_E f \, d\mu \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int_E f_n \, d\mu \leq \limsup_{n \to \infty} \int_E f_n\, d\mu  \leq \int_E f\, d\mu .$$

Comment: amazing. Very clever solution, except that I think you mistype the symbol. $X$ is the set and $M$ is algebra, so the integral in the second statement should be $\int_{X \setminus E}$, not $\int_{M \setminus E}$

Comment: @leducquang Of course, you are right; I mixed it up.

Comment: I think the $= \limsup_{n \to \infty} \left( \int f_n - \int_{X \backslash E} f_n \right)$ should be $\geq \limsup_{n \to \infty} \left( \int f_n - \int_{X \backslash E} f_n \right)$.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM Why? If $(a_n)_n$ and $(b_n)_n$ are two sequences such that $a_n$ converges, then $$\limsup (a_n + b_n ) = \lim_n a_n + \limsup_n b_n.$$ That's exactly what I used there.

Comment: @saz yes, my mistake.

Comment: Can you explain why $\lim \int f_n -\liminf \int_{X\E} f_n=\limsup (\int f_n -\int_{X\E} f_n)$? I can't understand how the liminf is equal to limsup here

Comment: @takecare i used the equality stated in my previous comment and $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} (-b_n) = - \liminf_{n \to \infty} b_n.$$

Comment: @saz what I don't understand is how $$\limsup\left(\int f_n - \int_{X\setminus E}f_n\right) = \limsup\int_E f_n$$ Can you explain or add a step or two you may have skipped?

Comment: I assume this is the case since $$\int_X f = \int_E f + \int_{X\setminus E}f = \lim\left(\int_E f_n + \int_{X\setminus E}f_n\right) = \lim\int_X f_n$$ and since we have $\int f = \lim \int f_n < \infty$ then we have $$\lim\int_E f_n = \lim\int_X f_n - \lim\int_{X\setminus E}f_n$$ If that is the case you should put a subscript $X$ in your integral so the reader understands

Comment: @Wolfy By $\int f_n$ I mean indeed $\int_X f_n$. So $$\int f_n - \int_{X \backslash E} f_n = \int_E f_n$$ by the linearity of the integral which obviously implies that $$\limsup \left( \int f_n - \int_{X \backslash E} f_n \right) = \limsup \int_E f_n.$$

Comment: okay then basically what I said above your comment?

Comment: @Wolfy Yes, but in your comment it should read "limsup" instead of "lim".

Comment: Right I just left it like that for simplicity thanks for the reply

Comment: Hi from the future. Can you please tell if you use the finiteness condition in the very first line (when you split up the integral into $E$ and $E^c$ parts) after ''we get'', and that that's the only place its used. Thanks in advance.