# Convergence for every measurable set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(f_n)$ non-negative measurable functions such that $f_n\to f$ and $\int f_n\to \int f<\infty$. We have to prove that $\int_E f_n\to \int_Ef$ for each $E$ measurable.

I know that if $f_n\to f$ then $f_n\cdot \chi_E\to f\cdot \chi_E$. Maybe we can use that in order to prove $\int f_n\cdot\chi _E\to\int f\cdot\chi_E$.

Could you give me any hint to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with $f_n\rightarrow f$? Maybe almost everywhere?

Comment: @FeliceIandoli pointwise.

Comment: This is answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678282/prove-that-int-ef-lim-int-ef-n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an application of Fatou's Lemma. Let $E \subset X$ be $\mu$-measurable. By using Fatou's Lemma twice we get 
$$\begin{align*}
 \int_E f \, \mathrm d\mu &= \int_X f \, \mathrm d\mu - \int_{E^{\mathrm c}} f \, \mathrm d\mu \\
&\geq \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_X f_n \, \mathrm d\mu - \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int_{E^{\mathrm c}} f_n \, \mathrm d\mu \quad \text{(Fatou)} \\
&= \limsup_{n \to \infty} \int_E f_n \, \mathrm d\mu \\
&\geq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int_E f_n \, \mathrm d\mu \\
&\geq \int_E f \, \mathrm d\mu \quad \text{(Fatou)}  \; ,
\end{align*} $$
so 
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_E f_n \, \mathrm d\mu = \int_E f \, \mathrm d\mu \; .$$