# If $f_n$ is integrable and non-negative, $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e, $\int f_n \rightarrow \int f$. prove $\int_A f_n \rightarrow \int_A f$

Tags: measure-theory

**Problem Statement**

Suppose $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is a measure space, each $f_n$ is integrable and non-negative, $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e, and $\int f_n  \rightarrow \int f$. prove that for each $A \in \mathcal{A}$,$$\int_A f_n \rightarrow \int_A f$$

**Background**

My text just introduced Monotone Convergence Theorem, Fatou's Lemma, and Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem.

**Attempt**

- **Theorem:** Suppose $f_n$, $g_n$, $f$, and $g$ are integrable, $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e, $g_n \rightarrow g$ a.e, $|f_n|\leq g_n$ for each
  $n$, and $\int g_n \rightarrow \int g$. Then $\int f_n \rightarrow
     \int f$.

  **Proof:** Since $\int_N h \ d\mu=0$ on a null set $N$, we may redefine $f_n$, $g_n$, $f$ and $g$ to be $0$ on the appropriate
  nullsets and consider the convergence on the entire space.$^{(1)}$
  Next, since $|f_n|\leq g_n$, we have $g+f>0$ and $g-f>0$. We use
  Fatou's lemma to furnish the following two arguments. First,
  \begin{align*} \int g+f \ d\mu&=\int\lim_{n \to \infty}\inf
     \left(f_n+g_n\right) \ d\mu \\ &\leq  \lim_{n \to \infty}\inf \int
     f_n+g_n \ d\mu\\ &=\lim_{n \to \infty}\inf \int f_n\ d\mu+\int g \
     d\mu, \end{align*} the last line following from the fact that $\int
     g_n \rightarrow \int g$. Thus, $$\int_f \leq \lim_{n \to \infty}\inf
     \int f_n\ d\mu.$$ similarly, \begin{align*} \int g-f \ d\mu
     &=\int\lim_{n \to \infty}\inf \left(g_n-f_n\right) \ d\mu \\ &\leq
     \lim_{n \to \infty}\inf \int g_n-f_n \ d\mu, \end{align*} so that 
  \begin{eqnarray*}
      - \int f \ d\mu &\leq \lim_{n \to \infty}\inf \int-f_n \ d\mu\\ &=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sup \int-f_n \ d\mu. \end{eqnarray*} Thus
  $$\int f \geq \lim_{n \to \infty}\sup \int f_n \ d\mu,$$ and we have
  the result.
- **Solution:**

  Note that in our problem, $f_n\chi_A \rightarrow f\chi_A$, $f \rightarrow f_n$, $|f_n\chi_A|\leq f_n$ for each $n$,
  and $\int f_n \rightarrow \int f$. Thus, our theorem yields $\int_A
     f_n \rightarrow \int_A f$. (Note that $\chi$ is the characteristic
  function$.

**My  Question(s)**

Is this correct? I felt awkward with $(1)$ but I think it was the right way to deal with the a.e convergence.

Comment: I think your statement (1) is fine. It almost doesn't seem to be necessary. At what point did you actually need it?

Comment: Since the problem mentioned a.e convergence, I felt that I had to deal with it in some dramatic way somehow..otherwise I didn't do anything too different from the standard proof of Fatou's lemma. (I should mention that the theorem I have listed was the previous problem to the problem being asked).

Comment: I think it's okay. If you're learning measure theory for the first time it doesn't hurt to include these kinds of statements. As you get more comfortable with the subject you might come to a point where you don't write these statements anymore, but they aren't wrong.

Comment: See also this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/678282/