# Given $f\in L^2(\mu)$, $\{f_n\}\in L^2(\mu)$, $f_n\rightarrow f$ a.e., and $\int|f_n|^2\rightarrow\int|f|^2$, then $f_n\rightarrow f$ in $L^2(\mu)$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

I am an undergraduate student taking a second course in real analysis. This is a homework problem.

The problem also suggests using Egorov's theorem. I have made an attempt but I couldn't finish the last step (maybe my approach is wrong).

Here it is:

[Need to show $\int|f_n-f|^2 \rightarrow 0$.]

Let $\epsilon > 0$.

Define $B_m = \{x\in X: d(0,x)<m\}$, for $m\in\mathbb{N}$.

Since $|f|^2$ is integrable there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\int_E |f|^2 < \frac{\epsilon}{4}$ whenever $\mu(E)<\delta$. (I think this is called "absolute continuity").

By Egorov's theorem there exists $A_\delta\subset E$ such that $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly on $A_\delta$ and $\mu(B_m - A_\delta)<\delta$.

Let $E = B_m - A_\delta$.

Then for all $n$

\begin{aligned}
\int_{B_m}|f_n-f|^2 &= \int_{A_\delta}|f_n-f|^2 + \int_{E}|f_n-f|^2 \\
&\le \int_{A_\delta}|f_n-f|^2 + \int_{E}|f_n|^2 + \int_{E}|f|^2
\end{aligned}

Now choose an integer $N$ such that for all $n > N$

$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{4\mu(A_\delta)}$$

on $A_\delta$ and

\begin{aligned}
&\left|\int_{E}|f_n|^2 - \int_{E}|f|^2\right| < \frac{\epsilon}{4} \\
\Rightarrow &\int_{E}|f_n|^2 < \int_{E}|f|^2 + \frac{\epsilon}{4}
\end{aligned}

[Satisfying this second condition is possible because $\int|f_n|^2\rightarrow\int|f|^2<\infty\Rightarrow\int_E|f_n|^2\rightarrow\int_E|f|^2$ ([from here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/678282/244687)).]

But $\int_{E}|f|^2 < \frac{\epsilon}{4}$ by absolute continuity since $\mu(E)<\delta$.

So for all $n > N$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{B_m}|f_n-f|^2 &\le \int_{A_\delta}|f_n-f|^2 + \left(\int_{E}|f|^2 + \frac{\epsilon}{4}\right) + \int_{E}|f|^2 \\
&< \int_{A_\delta}|f_n-f|^2 + \left(\frac{\epsilon}{4} + \frac{\epsilon}{4}\right) + \frac{\epsilon}{4} \\
&< \int_{A_\delta}\frac{\epsilon}{4\mu(A_\delta)} + \frac{3\epsilon}{4} \\
&< \frac{\epsilon}{4\mu(A_\delta)}\mu(A_\delta) + \frac{3\epsilon}{4} \\
&=\epsilon
\end{aligned}

So the problem is shown if $|f_n - f|^2$ has bounded support (i.e. if the support is contained in some $B_m$)...

[Continuous functions with compact support are dense in $L^p(\mu)$, $1 \le p < \infty$. Does this help me?]

I would really appreciate any hints, direction, or full proof you could provide. (I already submitted the homework.)

Comment: I haven't checked your proof in detail, but if you've shown $\int_{B_m} |f_n-f|^2 < \epsilon$ for all $m$, with $\epsilon$ independent of $m$, it suffices to take the limit as $m\to \infty$.

Comment: My choice of $N$ such that $\int_{B_m}|f_n-f|^2 < \epsilon$ holds for $n>N$ depends on $m$. Does this matter? Also thank you for your quick response.

Comment: Fatou's lemma and some elementary properties about $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ are sufficient to solve the question.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan I've read your answer below and found it very helpful. But I'm still having a hard time understanding if my own proof showed anything useful. user37208 said I could take the limit as $m\rightarrow\infty$, but I don't understand this argument.

Comment: @user37208 Could you tell me in a little more detail what you meant? (Sorry forgot to include notification first time.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that for any inner-product space, the norm induced by the inner-product
satisfies the so-called parallelogram identity $\left\Vert a+b\right\Vert ^{2}+\left\Vert a-b\right\Vert ^{2}=2\left\Vert a\right\Vert ^{2}+2\left\Vert b\right\Vert ^{2}$.

Therefore, we have $\left\Vert f_{n}-f\right\Vert ^{2}=2\left\Vert f_{n}\right\Vert ^{2}+2\left\Vert f\right\Vert ^{2}-\left\Vert f_{n}+f\right\Vert ^{2}$.
It is given that $||f_{n}||^{2}\rightarrow||f||^{2}$. Moreover, by
Fatou lemma, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
4\int|f|^{2} & = & \int\lim|f_{n}+f|^{2}\\
 & \leq & \liminf_{n}\int|f_{n}+f|^{2}\\
 & = & \liminf_{n}||f_{n}+f||^{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
It follows that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\limsup_{n}\left\Vert f_{n}-f\right\Vert ^{2} & \leq & \limsup_{n}\left(2\left\Vert f_{n}\right\Vert ^{2}+2\left\Vert f\right\Vert ^{2}\right)+\limsup_{n}\left(-\left\Vert f_{n}+f\right\Vert ^{2}\right)\\
 & = & 4||f||^{2}-\liminf_{n}||f_{n}+f||^{2}\\
 & \leq & 4||f||^{2}-4||f||^{2}\\
 & = & 0.
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore $||f_{n}-f||^2\rightarrow0$. (In the above, $||\cdot||$
of course denotes the $L^{2}$-norm)

Comment: To facilitate beginners, we show that $L^2$ is a vector space and that $fg\in L^1$ whenever $f,g\in L^2$. Clearly $L^2$ is closed under scalar multiplication. To show that $L^2$ is closed under vector addition, let $f,g\in L^2$. Observe that $(f+g)^2 \leq 2f^2 +2g^2$, so $f+g\in L^2$.
Lastly, $4fg = (f+g)^2-(f-g)^2\in L^1$.

Comment: Since this proof doesn't assume $f,f_n$ are real-valued (and because it's so short) I think I'll mark it as the accepted answer. Thank you for the clear explanation. Your comment was also helpful. Was the fact $f,g\in L^2\Rightarrow fg\in L^1$ assumed somewhere in the proof? Or were you just suggesting it is something good to know?

Comment: Yes. My proof works equally well for complex-valued case. However, in deriving that $L^2$ is a vector space, we need to replace $(f+g)^2\leq 2f^2 + 2g^2$ by $|f+g|^2\leq 2|f|^2 + 2|g|^2$ etc... Strictly speaking, in deriving the parallelogram identity, the fact that $fg\in L^1$ whenever $f,g\in L^2$ is not needed. I include it here because  people may write $\int (f+g)^2 = \int f^2 + 2\int fg + \int g^2$. In this case, we need to justify the integrability of $fg$.

Comment: I see, thank you. Just making sure I wasn't missing where it (integrability of $fg$) had used.

Comment: One more remark: Strictly speaking, $||\cdot||$ is only a semi-norm unless we identify $f$ and $g$ whenever $f=g$ almost everywhere.
If we regard $L^2(\mu)$ as a Hilbert space, then elements in $L^2(\mu)$ are not functions but equivalent classes of functions.
Any two square-integrable functions are within the same equivalent class iff the two functions equal almost everywhere.

Comment: If $x_0$ is a point fixed at the very beginning and if we regard $L^2(\mu)$ as a Hilbert space,
then it is very wrong to write:

Let $f\in L^2(\mu)$. Consider $f(x_0) = \ldots$ and draw conclusion upon it.
We need to bear in mind that we may choose two functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ in the equivalent class $f$.
Then $f_1 = f_2$ almost everywhere but $f_1(x_0)\neq f_2(x_0)$.

Comment: Ddumb question sorry bbut where did that 4 come from?

Answer (score 2):

Put
$$A_n = \int ((f_n)_+ -f_+)^2 d\mu = \int (f_n)_+^2  d\mu + \int f_+^2 d\mu -2 \int (f_n)_+ f_+ d\mu,$$
and
$$B_n = \int ((f_n)_- -f_-)^2 d\mu = \int (f_n)_-^2  d\mu + \int f_-^2 d\mu -2 \int (f_n)_- f_- d\mu.$$
Hence 
$$A_n + B_n = \int f_n^2 d\mu + \int f^2 d\mu -2\left(\underbrace{\int (f_n)_+ f_+ d\mu + \int (f_n)_- f_- d\mu}_{C_n}\right).$$
We have $(f_n)+ \to f_+$ and $(f_n)_- \to f_-$ a.e, hence by Fatou lemma, we have
$$\liminf C_n \geq \liminf \int (f_n)_+ f_+ d\mu + \liminf \int (f_n)_- f_- d\mu = \int f_+^2 d\mu + \int f_-^2 d\mu = \int f^2 d\mu.$$
In other hand, we have
$$C_n \leq \int \frac{(f_n)_+^2 +f_+^2}2 d\mu + \int \frac{(f_n)_-^2 + f_-^2} 2 d\mu = \int\frac{f_n^2 + f^2}2 d\mu, $$
hence
$$\limsup C_n \leq \int f^2 d\mu.$$
Thus, we have $C_n \to \int f^2 d\mu$ and then $A_n + B_n \to 0$. Since $A_n, B_n \geq 0$, we must have $A_n \to 0$ and $B_n \to 0$. Using the inequality $(a+b)^2 \leq 2(a^2 + b^2)$, we have
$$0\leq \int (f_n -f)^2 d\mu \leq 2(A_n + B_n)$$
which implies
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int (f_n -f)^2 d\mu = 0.$$

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. This was a really clear proof for when $f, f_n$ are real. When you were finding an upper bound for $C_n$ and used the arithmetic-geometric means inequality that was neat.